# Two Picture Boxes that cycle through images on each button click

Tags: c#, .net, picturebox

When I say I'm a beginner, I really am as fresh as you can get so apologies up front!

What I am trying to do is in a form have two picture boxes and a button.  When I click on the button it picks 2 new images from my image folder and it will do this a total of 5 times

Any ideas how I approach this - Here's what I have so far for the button click

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      pictureBox1.Load(@"C:\Resources\PICT01.JPG");
      pictureBox2.Load(@"C:\Resources\PICT02.JPG");
}
```

Any answers really need to be basic as I am just learning !  Thanks in advance

Comment: based on what you are doing or have ..do you want to load 2 images 5 times when the user clicks the button once..? if so then this approach is not correct.. you will need 5 picture boxes if I am understanding your issue correctly.. or you will need to create Dynamically 5 picture boxes..

Comment: Thanks DJ Kraze - I need  the 2 picture boxes to load a different image each time the button is clicked up to a maximum of 5 clicks..Make sense?

Comment: Are you needing these images to be random or just a hardcode progression

Comment: I understand what you are needing..but your current code will always load the same 2 images.. you need to load Random Images..

Comment: Hi Mark - Random would be good

Comment: thats my problem DJ - I dont know how to do it - I have spent about 20 hours on tutorials and still cant figure it out ! THis is my first ever attempt to code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a global int to keep track of how often you have switched pictures, and handle that number in your button1_click.

I'm no expert myself but here's how i would do it. A switch is ideal here because you need to check 5 different possibilities.

```
//global int
int count = 0;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  count++;
  switch(count)
  {
     case 1:
       //load image 1 and 2
       break;
     case 2:
       //load image 3 and 4
       break;
     case 3:
       //load image 5 and 6
       break;
     case 4:
       //load image 7 and 8
       break;
     case 5:
       //load image 9 and 10
       break;
     default: 
       break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Tim - Thank you so much - THat is exactly what I needed - as mentioned I am stuck on it a while so this really gets me out of a hole !!!

Answer (score 0):

This sample program will create a list of all jpg-files in MyPictures folder and pick random pictures from the list, when the list is empty it will raise an exception.

```
public Form1()
{
    // Reading pictures from My Pictures:
    string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolders.MyPictures);
    DictionaryInfo myPictures = new DictionaryInfo(path);
    FPictureFiles = myPictures.GetFiles("*.jpg", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();
}
private List<FileInfo> FPictureFiles;
private Random FRandom = new Random();

private void button1_Click(object sender)
{
    pictureBox1.Load(PickFile());
    pictureBox2.Load(PickFile());
}

private string PickFile()
{
    if (FPictureFiles.Count == 0) throw new Exception("No more picture files");

    int index = FRandom.Next(FPictureFiles.Count);
    string filename = FPictureFiles[index].FullName;
    FPictureFiles.RemoveAt(index);
    return filename;
}
```

I hope this will help you in your quest.

Comment: thanks so much for taking the time to do this - again this code is quite interestion and I will 100% try to implement it - It is helping me to learn !

Answer (score 0):

You may try to create a new `List<string>` which lists all files having a specific extension of your selection. Then, initialize a new `Random` class which gets a random number within a specific range considering that the range will not be more than our `List<string>.Count` value.

**Example**

Assuming that `CurrentClicks` identifies a new integer and `MaximumClicks` is our maximum value

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    button1.Click += new EventHandler(button1_Click); //Link the Click event of button1 to button1_Click
}

const int MaximumClicks = 5; //Initialize a new constant int of value 5 named MaximumClicks
int CurrentClicks = 0; //Initialize a new variable of name CurrentClicks as an int of value 0
```

the following may apply

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (CurrentClicks < MaximumClicks) //Continue if CurrentClicks is less than 5
    {
        string FilesPath = @"D:\Resources\International"; //Replace this with the targeted folder
        string FileExtensions = "*.png"; //Applies only to .png file extensions. Replace this with your desired file extension (jpg/bmp/gif/etc)
        List<string> ItemsInFolder = new List<string>(); //Initialize a new Generic Collection of name ItemsInFolder as a new List<string>
        foreach (string ImageLocation in Directory.GetFiles(FilesPath, FileExtensions)) //Get all files in FilesPath creating a new string of name ImageLocation considering that FilesPath returns a directory matching FileExtensions considering that FileExtensions returns a valid file extension within the targeted folder
        {
            ItemsInFolder.Add(ImageLocation); //Add ImageLocation to ItemsInFolder
        }
        Random Rnd = new Random(); //Initialize a new Random class of name Rnd
        int ImageIndex = Rnd.Next(0, ItemsInFolder.Count); //Initialize a new variable of name ImageIndex as a random number from 0 to the items retrieved count
        pictureBox1.Load(ItemsInFolder[ImageIndex]); //Load the random image based on ImageIndex as ImageIndex belongs to a random index in ItemsInFolder
        CurrentClicks++; //Increment CurrentClicks by 1
    }
    else
    {
        //Do Something (MaximumClicks reached)
    }
}
```

This will get the file locations within the provided folder matching a specified extension. Then, loads a random file from the file locations gathered into a `PictureBox` of name `pictureBox1`.

This will however not avoid files that were added previously to the `PictureBox`. If you would like to avoid duplicates, you may create a new `int` array or `List<int>` and add every `ImageIndex` that was applied to the `PictureBox` but it's recommended to go with `List<int>` because it seems easier to manage

**Example**

```
List<int> AlreadyAdded = new List<int>();
redo:
    Random Rnd = new Random();
    int ImageIndex = Rnd.Next(0, ItemsInFolder.Count);
    if (AlreadyAdded.Contains(ImageIndex)) //Continue within this block if the item already exists in AlreadyAdded
    {
        goto redo;
    }                
    AlreadyAdded.Add(ImageIndex); //Add ImageIndex to AlreadyAdded
```

Thanks,

 I hope you find this helpful :)

Comment: wow - THis is really good - I will try implement that next week.  As I said I am a beginner and am learning all the terminology and what code go's where etc.  Your comments in the code are very helpful in pointing me in the right direction

Comment: @jimbob--arooney I'm glad you had your issue resolved. Have a nice day :)